# How to create a row object that contains related objects in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, relationship, dbix-class

When you [`create`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#create) a Row object in `DBIx::Class` you can pass related objects as values, e.g.

```
my $author = $authors_rs->find(1);
my $book = $books_rs->create({ author => $author, title => 'title' });
```

However, if you later use the `author` accessor, the object is retrieved again from the database. Is it possible to create an object so that the associated object can be accessed without the additional query?

Comment: That's a good question. You might want to ask it on the DBIx::Class mailing list, where the developers hang out.  It seems to me that caching the author object in the book's scope after the creation should be possible.  But it might be that DBIC always biases towards retrieving the related record to insure freshness.

Comment: Posted to the DBIx::Class mailing list: http://lists.scsys.co.uk/pipermail/dbix-class/2012-August/010741.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just copying what you want from $author into some plain old Perl variables?

If you want to copy a whole structure, the [clone](http://search.cpan.org/~rdf/Clone-0.31/Clone.pm) module may help (I don't have experience with this module; I just found it online).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm understanding you correctly, but if I am, perhaps you want to look into the [`prefetch`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#prefetch) functionality to automatically be ready for calling those other related row objects.

For example, in [`Galileo`](http://p3rl.org/Galileo), when listing all pages (articles) I use this mechanism to get the related author objects for each page object ([see here](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo/blob/master/lib/Galileo/files/templates/admin/pages.html.ep#L4)).

---

Ok so if the point is to store one object in another, you might want to inject some extra data into the object.

UNTESTED:

```
## some initial checks (run these only once)

# check that method name is available
die "Cannot use method 'extra_data'" if $book->can('extra_data');

# check that the reftype is a hash
require Scalar::Util;
die "Incorrect underlying type" unless Scalar::Util::reftype($book) eq 'HASH';

# check that the key is available
die "Key unavailable" if exists $book->{'my_extra_data'};

{
  no strict 'refs';
  # create a simple accessor for a hash stored in an object
  *{ ref($book) . '::extra_data' } = sub {
    my $self = shift;

    #return all extra data if called without args
    return $self->{my_extra_data} unless @_; 

    my $key = shift;
    if (@_) {
      $self->{my_extra_data}{$key} = shift;
    }

    return $self->{my_extra_data}{$key};
  };
}

$book->extra_data( author => $author );

#then later

my $stored_author = $book->extra_data('author');
```

Comment: `prefetch` is used for `JOIN`s (i.e. `SELECT`s) while I have a different use case. I have a related object already and want to have it stored in the newly created object (which has the foreign key) so that it doesn't need to be retrieved again (in different file/scope of code)

Comment: ok, so you have some code which return a row object into another scope (otherwise you would need another `SELECT`). Can't you just return both objects instead of one? Perhaps you want to return a collection "object" which contains both? 

What i'm saying is that by whatever channel you are moving your row object, you should be able to move both, I would think.